# Retrain of a neural network

Tags: math, machine-learning

I have already trained a NN with training data set `[X,Y]`. Lets consider this model is called `M`. Now, I have a new data set `[Xnew,Ynew]`. I would like to Update my model `M` with data set `[Xnew,Ynew]` without retraining it from scratch.

My question is: is it possible to update the model this way or I must retrain this? If it is possible to update, how?

Comment: The answer is no. For some kinds of models, it is possible to summarize the data in a relatively small number of parameters, and then update the summary with some new data, and rebuild the model from the updated summary. Such a summary is called the "sufficient statistics" for the model. Sufficient statistics unfortunately exist only for a relatively narrow family of models, called the exponential family, which doesn't include neural nets with hidden units.  In the absence of sufficient statistics, you might be able to find heuristics to speed up training.

Comment: What's with the '$' in your question? You can see that they do not result to any special rendering, can't you?

Comment: @RobertDodier your answer is questionable; in practice, under very general conditions, it is certainly possible to just keep training the network with new data, as the answer below suggests

Comment: @desertnaut The error surface of the network is determined by the training data. Training from existing weights means only that you are starting from a different point than if you had chosen the starting point randomly. If you train to convergence, you'll find the same point as if you started at random (modulo multiple local minima). If you don't train to convergence, it's unclear what properties the result has. In particular there is no guarantee that it is equivalent to a network which was trained from all the old plus new data.

Comment: @RobertDodier agree on the unclear & no guarantee parts; what I'm saying is that, given the generality (and even vagueness) of the question as expressed, to say simply that "the answer is no" is oversimplification. After all, one can argue that transfer learning itself falls indeed under the "retraining" label, as (vaguely) described here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you’re doing e.g. backpropagation. You can take the weights trained on the first data set as the starting point for the training on the second data set, instead of starting with random weights.

Whether this is a sensible thing to do or not is of course highly depends on your data sets and the network topology.